# You have already activated builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, gemfile

I get the following error message when loading my Rails application:

`You have already activated builder 3.0.4, but your Gemfile requires builder 3.0.3. Consider using bundle exec.`

Stack trace:

```
0   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    31  in `block in setup'
1   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   12  in `block in each'
2   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   12  in `each'
3   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb   12  in `each'
4   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb    17  in `setup'
5   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler.rb    107 in `setup'
6   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb  326 in `prepare_app_process'
7   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb  176 in `block in initialize_server'
8   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb  563 in `report_app_init_status'
9   /usr/local/ruby/1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/classic_rails/application_spawner.rb  174 in `initialize_server'
```

It seems as though `passenger` activated `3.0.4` but my application Gemfile still has `3.0.3`. I can add `gem 'builder', '3.0.4'` in my Gemfile but it will happen again when a new version comes out. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: "I get the following error message" ... when doing *what*?

Comment: "Application failed to start" message from passenger. This message is displayed when an application fails to start.

Comment: If you don't update passenger, and don't change your gemfile, you shouldn't have a conflict. Specifying the exact patch value of the gem will force it to that version always.

Comment: @agmcleod Is that good practice?

Comment: Well you don't want to change production software willy nilly. If there are crucial fixes, you need to do the setup in a staging server first, make sure it works and update things manually on the production server. My point is it won't update until you tell it to.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when using RVM, or just a separate version of ruby with respect to the system's default.

Configure RVM to provide passenger the same ruby you use for development (and where bundler installs your gems).

https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/

Comment: `First of all there's passenger-install-apache2-module and passenger-install-nginx-module. At the end of the installation it outputs a PassengerRuby configuration snippet for the web server. Its value is set to the RVM Ruby wrapper script that corresponds with the RVM Ruby and RVM gemset that was used to run the installer. This should be all you need for configuration of Passenger 3!` I have Passenger 3, do I still need to configure anything else? I believe it's using the same Ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this elegant way or not I am using binstub.
Run:

```
bundle install --binstubs
export PATH=./bin:$PATH
```

You may read more at http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2011/07/18/stop-typing-bundle-exec/